# Interpreting and Solving This Partial Derivation Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

For a homework question, I am given the following:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x,y) = \alpha x^2 + \beta xy+ \gamma y^2$ for some $\alpha , \beta , \gamma \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
>
> (A) Compute $Df(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$
>
> (B) Show $Df(x)(y) = Df(y)(x)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$
>
> (C) Show $Df(x)(x) = 2f(x)$

For part (A), I just took the partial derivative of f with respect to x, but for parts (B) and (C) I am running into problems with how to interpret the question. Here are my assumptions:

For **B**, I am assuming this is asking for us to show that the partial derivative of x and then y is equal to the partial derivative of y and then x.

For **C**, I am assuming this is asking us to take the partial derivative with respect to x twice

How would you all interpret parts (B) and (C)?

Comment: This notation is not entirely standardized.  Your best bet would be to review your course materials and see what notational conventions they establish.  For what it's worth it seems extremely unlikely to me that this is asking you to differentiate twice; rather, one input is the point at which you are differentiating, and the other is a vector you input into the derivative to get out the directional derivative.  Note in particular that $x$ and $y$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ so it **definitely** is not telling you to take partial derivatives with respect to the variables $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Please clarify the notation you use.

Comment: @Jethro according to our textbook, $D$ stands for the partial derivative, which is why I assumed I would be solving for the partial derivatives.

Comment: @cz46 Not just $D$, but the entire $Df(x)(y)$. Do you mean $x,y\in \mathbb R$? Do you mean $\partial_ x f (x,y)$?

Comment: @Jethro as stated above, the x and y are contained in $\mathbb{R}^2$. In terms of the $D$, I am beginning to believe that it represents a matrix of Jacobians. Overall, I believe the questions have to do with differentiating linear combinations.

Comment: @Jethro moreover, just differentiating constant and linear functions.