# Directional Derivatives and Equivalence

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

This is a continuation from [this question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564861/interpreting-and-solving-this-partial-derivation-question?noredirect=1#comment7330260_3564861). To reiterate, here is the question:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x,y) = \alpha x^2 + \beta xy+ \gamma y^2$ for some $\alpha , \beta , \gamma \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
>
> (A) Compute $Df(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$
>
> (B) Show $Df(x)(y) = Df(y)(x)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$
>
> (C) Show $Df(x)(x) = 2f(x)$

I now understand that (B) is asking to prove that the directional derivatives $D_yf(x) = D_xf(y)$. How does one go about proving this $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: This is peculiar notation. What is $Df(x)$ meant to signify?

Comment: @copper.hat I believe the linear map.

Comment: That is not an answer. What linear map? Map from what to what?

Comment: @copper.hat after reviewing material, it represents the name of the derived function. So if we had $f(x) = x^5$ then $Df(x) = 5x^4$. More over, if we have $Df(c)$ where $c$ represents a point, then it would be $Df(c) = 5c^4$.

Comment: You use $x$ as a scalar at the start and then switch to the plane. Using the usual notation, $Df(x)$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Using the usual notation, $Df(x)(y)$ would be the derivative at $x$ evaluated in the direction $y$. The rest is just plugging in values.